# Does Titan-1.0.0-hadoop1 work with keylines

Tags: titan

As far as i have searched, keylines were installed in titan only with rexster. Can we install keylines graph visualization with Titan-1.0.0-hadoop1? There were do documents available for it as well.

Comment: Why not give it a try ? Find for yourself.

Comment: I have searched for it. I want to connect Titan-1.0.0hadoop1 with keylines. But all that was shown was for the lower versions of titan which had rexster in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is listed on the KeyLines website. http://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/titan/

Quick start guide is available for Titan 1.0 but you have to register with them first.

See also this TinkerPop 3 specific blog linked from the previous link http://cambridge-intelligence.com/visualizing-graphs-tinkerpop3-migration-guide/